# What's wrong with this object declaration?

Tags: c++, class, object

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
    public:
        int x;
    A() {
        x=1;
        cout << x <<endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A b();
    cout << b.x << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Running this results in compilation error: Error: request for member 'x' in 'b', which is of non-class type 'A()' "cout<< b.x <

Comment: You declared the object but never created it. Try to create it with the 'new' keyword.
A b = new b(); In your case it is like a function definition.

Comment: Google "c++ most vexing parse" to find out what the compiler really did with that code.  Drop the parentheses.

Comment: This is the C++ most vexing parse.   `A b();` declares a function named `b()` that accepts no arguments and returns an `A`.   It does not declare a variable.

Comment: @Karavana - your suggestion is not valid in C++.

Comment: @Karavana he is not using pointers so the new keyword would not fix this code. A b = A(); would actually be more valid

Comment: @WillAnderson you'r right, in my comment it shoulda been A* b = new A();
or as you said, A b = A();